# plugin to capture a site page preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I've seen a plugin that does this but I can't find it now!

I'm trying to capture a page preview image for a bookmarklet I'm building. So when a user bookmarks a site I can have a little snaptshot of the page Do you know what plugin I am talking about? Thanks!

As in this page
http://www.stumbleupon.com/discover/toprated/

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the one you were looking for but perhaps you can adapt this [cucumber extension](http://gemcutter.org/gems/cucumber-screenshot) that uses webkit to capture the browser.